# typescript concat warning no overloading match

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
console.log([].concat(0, 123))
```

I've no clue what the error means

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(...items: ConcatArray<never>[]): never[]', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '0' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ConcatArray<never>'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(...items: ConcatArray<never>[]): never[]', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '0' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ConcatArray<never>'.ts(2769)
```

I assign to a variable and declare any type I still see the error.

Comment: This `console.log(([] as number[]).concat(0, 123))` works. Check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54117175 for further information.

Comment: @Yoshi I was curious what keyword you searched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
console.log(([] as any[]).concat(0, 123));
```

For more info, check this [github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10479)