# Why will `Object.assign` create an array of type `never[] & number[]`?

Tags: typescript

Here is the code:

```
const arr = [1,2,3]
const res1 = arr.slice()
const res2 = Object.assign([],arr)
```

If I do a shallow clone with `arr.slice()`, then I will get a new array `res1` of type `number[]`, which is the same as `arr`. But if I do that with `Object.assign()`, what I get is an array `res2` of type `never[] & number[]`.

Why the types of `res2` will contain the type `never[]`? And how could it be the type of `number[]` while it also be the type of `never[]` (by `&`)?

Comment: The TypeScript intersection type return for `Object.assign[]` is an approximation of what actually happens. So `Object.assign({a: 1}, {b: 2})` will be of type `{a: number} & {b: number}` which is correct, but `Object.assign({a: 1}, {a: ""}` will be of type `{a: number} & {a: string}` which is incorrect. It's not always correct, but it's useful in many circumstances.  An empty array `[]` will sometimes be inferred as type `never[]` (it is "auto-typed" if you set props or push to it, but you're not doing that here) and so you have this result.  I'd do [this](//tsplay.dev/wEGBgm) instead.

Comment: If that makes sense and answers your question I could write up an answer. If not, please [edit] the question to explain what's missing so someone can address it.

Comment: If you're looking for another way to create a shallow array copy, you can simply use `[...arr]`

Comment: @jcalz I think it makes sense. But one question I still don't understand is that "An empty array [] will sometimes be inferred as type never[]". What `sometimes` actually means? Also, for `const arr = []`, the type can be inferred as `any[]`. Why in this question it is `never[] & number[]` instead of `any[] & number`?

Comment: It is not really `any[]` if you're using `--strictNullChecks` and `--noImplicitAny`, it is *auto-typed*, meaning the compiler *evolves* it later based on what you put into it (see [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#example-4)).  So it's based on control flow, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mZbXJm).  That `any[]` you see with quickinfo is not really accurate. If you have an empty array and the compiler needs to infer a type for it, it will tend to be `never[]`.

Comment: This is mentioned in the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54117100/why-does-typescript-infer-the-never-type-when-reducing-an-array-with-concat question that @Kaiido wants to close this one as a duplicate of.  You kind of have *two* questions here... "why does `[]` get inferred as `never[]`" and "why does `Object.assign()` return an incorrect intersection type"? Which one is your primary question?

Comment: See https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29795 for the `never[]` vs `any[]` issue

Comment: @jcalz Thanks. From the reference you gave I have learned about some useful infos. The reason why `arr` being type `any[]` in `const arr = []` is because after declaring `arr`, we still have a chance to add all kinds of members to that array.  And TS could use control flow analysis to extend its type gradually. So initial type being `any[]` means the possible extendable.

Comment: @jcalz But for `Object.assign([],arr)`, `[]` will be kept being an empty array for a while. And it is difficult to use control flow analysis to do the inference job. So in this condition, `[]` is inferred as type `never[]` instead of `any[]`.  It is actually a empty union. But union type shouldn't be empty according to union's definition, so in this case, it has to be `never[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the type of `Object.assign`:

```
Object.assign<T, U>(target: T, source: U): T & U
```

I.e. the returned type is the intersection of whatever objects you pass as `target` and `source`. Without explicit type declarations typescript has to infer the types of the passed arguments here. For `arr` this is correctly inferred as `number[]` but for the first argument/`target` - since it is an empty array and so the type of the non-existent elements can not be inferred - it is inferred as `never[]`, thus resulting in the return type `never[] & number[]`.

You could achieve your expected result by explicitly giving the type of `target`, e.g.:

```
const res2 = Object.assign([] as number[], arr)
```

Comment: But if I write `const arr = []`, the type can be inferred as `any[]`. Why in this question it is `never[] & number[]` instaed of `any[] & number`?

Comment: It's an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types), not a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types).

Comment: @jcalz you're correct. I updated the answer to fix this error.