# Why is a = null ?? [] of type never[]?

Tags: typescript, type-inference, typescript-never

Why am I getting different type inference here for the array ?

```
const a = []; // any[]
const b = null ?? []; // never[]
```

[Demo here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAhhC8EG0C6BuCB6d0B2BPZAsAFCiQBGcE2ArsMBAPwOKoZbYgBuIATshEA)

Comment: Does this happen with `strictNullChecks`?

Comment: The strange part for me is that the first one is of type `any[]` and there is no compiler error, even though `noImplicitAny` is enabled. Normally I would expect an empty array to be typed as `never[]` if it cannot be inferred from context. The answer is likely that there is a special case for `const something = [];`.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36987, https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46492

Comment: More links: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29795#issuecomment-461597638 https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/11432 ; Discussion in the comments on a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54117100/why-does-typescript-infer-the-never-type-when-reducing-an-array-with-concat#comment95067334_54117175 ; Sorry, all this looks completely opinion-based. Inferring the "correct" `never[]` was confusing in most cases, so they've hard-coded something else for this very special case, and now that's just what it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "correct" thing to do would be to infer `never[]` for the empty array literal `[]`, because the type of an array literal is the join of the types of its elements, and `never` is the join of an empty set.

However, since inferring `never[]` is usually not what the user intends when writing `const a = []`, this particular case received a [very special treatment in the compiler](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/11432), and now it starts by implicitly inferring `any[]`, and then refining the type based on the subsequent control flow.

There does not seem to be any deeper meaning behind it: it's just what turns out to be the most useful in most cases.